# Types of work addition: microconsulting

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Is it possible to add "microconsulting" (or some other term that means something similar) to the "Types of work" in the careers profile?

I think this is sufficiently different to "temporary contract" and "remote", as both of these suggest full time, whereas I'm available for just a few hours a week at a per-hour rate. Even if there were a "part time" option, I think that it wouldn't really be clear that each set of hours would need to be individually booked and paid for.

Essentially this would make the careers profile be a little bit like what https://www.airpair.com offers (disclosure: on which I am an "expert").

Comment: is there no consulting?

Comment: @Tim No consulting either. That would be better for me than all the available options though.

Comment: If microconsulting is a word then please direct me to the marketing douche who invented it so that I may slay him.

Comment: @Won't Better suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: @Won't, don't you think the OP was the one who invented microconsulting?

Comment: @Won't Microconsultants are like consultants except they have mustaches, wear flannel shirts, limit their companies to 4 employees or less, and only use programming languages listed here: http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/